# How to properly set events for dynamic XUL elements?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a toolbar extension that generates dynamic `toolbarbutton` and `menuitem` elements. These items are typically constructed like this:

```
tempMenuItem = document.createElement("menuitem");
tempMenuItem.setAttribute("label",  "Some Label");
tempMenuItem.setAttribute("tooltiptext", "Some Tooltip");
tempMenuItem.setAttribute("oncommand", "myObject.someFunction()");
```

This code works just fine, but I get the following warning when I submit my extension to the official add-on repository:

> on* attribute being set using setAttribute
>
> Warning: To prevent vulnerabilities, event handlers (like 'onclick' and 'onhover') should always be defined using addEventListener.

How else can I set the appropriate command handler for these dynamic elements? I know this is simply a warning, but being the obsessive compulsive programmer that I am, I'd like to do things in the cleanest way possible. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you obviously use [`addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) as the suggestion says:

```
tempMenuItem.addEventListener("command", function(event)
{
  myObject.someFunction();
}, false);
```

Or somewhat shorter if you also use the [`Function.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
tempMenuItem.addEventListener("command", myObject.someFunction.bind(myObject), false);
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't clear to me how event listeners could be applied to dynamic elements, but your example makes perfect sense.